# Indexing arrays

Tags: objective-c, macos, indexing

### Overview

I have painting APP. It registers mouse events and sends it to NSMutableArray. Later values from array are being transfered to GLfloat and drawn like vertex array. So all brush stroke is redrawn at every mouse event.

### What I want to do?

I want to implement undo-redo functions and something like brush stroke variety (softness and etc), so I need somehow to do that every vertex (mouse event location) could have few additional settings. I want to ask if it is possible at all.

### Explanation

If user draws *10 points* with *100% softness* (in one mouse drag) and then changes softness to *0%* and draws, first *10 point's* brush texture has to be set to *img1* and second brush stroke brush's texture has to be set to *img2*.

If there would be possibility for indexing arrays (for example something like this `NSMutableArray *array[i++] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`) I think it would be possible to do something similar to what I want pretty easy. But is it possible? Or maby you could suggest any other solution?

P.S. `NSMutableArray *array[i++] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` doesn't shows me any error, but does't works too.

---

Attempt using `NSMutableDictionary`

At mousedown and mousedragged:

```
locll = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
NSValue *locationValuell = [NSValue valueWithPoint:locll];
[vertices addObject:locationValuell];
```

at mouseUp

```
NSString *index = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aIndex++];
[aDict setObject:vertices forKey:index];
NSArray *allKeys = [aDict allKeys];
NSLog(@"dict count: %ld", [allKeys count]);
NSString *index1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aIndex];
NSMutableArray *a = [aDict objectForKey:index1];
NSLog(@"a count:%li", [a count]);
```

at initWithCoder

```
int aIndex = 0;
```

dict count returns how many objects are stored in dictionary. And it works. But later when I try to get array back from dictionary, I check how much objects array has and it returns 0.

Comment: Because for me it is useful both languages answers (c++ and objective-c). I can use them both. I can mix them.

Comment: in the question is now reference to c++ or objective-c++. so many people will the see title and the tag c++ they are interested in but then will have now clue about the question itself. quite annoying. further-more xcode is just an IDE, not important for the question either. you could develop objective-c apps in vi and compile on commandline as-well.

Comment: You are really strange person

Comment: why? because i want to limit noise in stack overflow? you should consult the faq

Comment: I find developers strange, who ask for help but clearly didnt show any afford, to first research and than provide a clear question with a proper title and valid tagging, as any developer should understand, how important a good question is if you want to receive a good answer.

Comment: I don't understand how afford can be shown through question's tags or title. What answer I want is only mine business. If it was OK for me to get answers in c++ language, I added c++ tag. c++ and objective-c is not so different languages. You're not a teacher for me who could teach me how to ask "good" question to get "good" answer. So I am not interested in your philosophy. Good luck :)

Comment: This is not my philosophy, it is how stackoverflow works. C++ and Objective-C are very different languages. the only thing they have in common is the C-core. and even that is not really compatible, as C++ is not a strict superset of C, while Objective-C is. And it gets even more different, if you are talking about functionalities, that are either part of the C++ STL or Cocoa/OPENSTEP. most things in C++ are done during compile time, while in Objective-C nearly everything is done during runtime. For me those languages are so different as languages can be that are built on english vocabulary.

Comment: They aren't so different in this situation. As I told, it was OK for me to get answer in C++ language because my program is in mixed code (C++ and Objective-C), thats why c++ tag was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question right , here's what you can do :

- Every mouse drag will be 1 path i.e an `NSMutableArray` of points
  with same softness level.
- Add this to a `NSMutableDictionary` with ***Key***    as the
  softness-level  and ***Value*** with this path array.
- Iterate through the dictionary to get the corresponding ***Key-Value***
  pair and draw the strokes.
- For **UNDO**  just delete the last object of the dictionary and store in
  a temporary dictionary.
- For **REDO** fetch it back from the temporary dictionary and add to the main dictionary.

---

Thanx for posting the code. I tried this and it works absolutely fine :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int aIndex = 0;
    NSMutableDictionary *aDict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *vertices = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [vertices addObject:@"one"];
    [vertices  addObject:@"two"];
    [vertices addObject:@"three"];

    NSString *index = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aIndex++];
    [aDict setObject:vertices forKey:index];

    NSArray *allKeys = [aDict allKeys];
    NSLog(@"dict count: %d", [allKeys count]);  // Prints 1

    NSMutableArray *a =[aDict objectForKey:index];
    NSLog(@"a item count is :%d", [a count]);   // prints 3
}
```

NOTE: Be careful with the index you are passing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looks like something I have been looking for. I'll try this solution and look if it is really suitable for my situation. After that I will give feedback.

Comment: While trying to use your suggested solution I met one problem. How to get array back from dictionary? `NSMutableArray *undo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[aDict objectForKey:currIndex]];` seems to be not working.

Comment: I dont understand why this should not work. If you can just post some of your code maybe it'll be of some help.

Comment: I increased index too much times, so I tried to get back array witch doesn't exist. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can work with your array as other objects so, you can use `[YourArray insertObject:YourArray atIndex:i++]]` then use `[YourArray objectAtIndex:i]` to get your array back

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for answer. But actually it is not what i am looking for. I know it. But I need to at every new mouse event add object to new automatically created array, so that later they could be drawn as different vertex arrays.

Comment: at the beginning of the mouse event create new array, fill it with values then add the new array to the general one as i mentioned before

Comment: Then there is no use of creating new array if later I add it to general one. By the way its really now what I am looking for. @Nayan suggested solution looks to be something similar to what I am looking for. But thanks for trying to help. Up vote for efforts

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vector or VAOs and add a VAO to it for each brush stroke. Wrap the VAOs in a class that also holds additional information such as brush type. That should let you identify each stroke's type and correctly render them.